# mypy ignoring file in favor of stub

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following directory structure:

```
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
foo/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    foo.pyi
tests/
    test_foo.py
```

When I run `mypy .`, only `__init__.py`, `foo.pyi`, and `test_foo.py` are examined while `foo.py` is ignored.  I don't have any mypy configuration options set in either pyproject.toml or setup.cfg.

I can confirm that `foo.py` is ignored either by running

```bash
$ rm -rf .mypy_cache; mypy . -v 2>&1 | grep Parsing
```

or by inserting obvious type errors.

Comment: What happens if you add a `stubs/` dir, move foo.pyi to it and tell mypy about it with `export MYPYPATH=./stubs/` or similar?

Comment: A-ha!  That did it!

Comment: @FiddleStix, could you explain why that worked? You can also post that as the answer.

Comment: I wish I knew. I think it might actually be a fluke that this worked as I can't claim to understand mypy's search path priority at all.